# If in the Fisher's exact test, one did not condition on the margin totals, how would the margin totals be factored in the calulation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test

It states in the following post [What does the assumption of the Fisher test that "The row and column totals should be fixed" mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/441139/what-does-the-assumption-of-the-fisher-test-that-the-row-and-column-totals-shou) that:

> Fisher's exact test conditions on the margin totals, meaning that it
> does not use any information about independence that might be
> inferable from the margin totals

Suppose we didn't condition on the margin totals. In that case, how would we model the distribution of the margin totals and how would that factor into a calculation?

Would it just be what the Chi Square test assumes?